# how to disable all browser not save my website cached data for all my website users and all time new updated and fresh website open

Tags: wordpress, plugins

how to disable all browser not save my Wordpress website cached data for all my website users and all time new updated and fresh website open because when i publish new posts chrome,opera don't show new posts and show old post

Answer (score 0):

For chrome: 
Go to developer's console - Network's tab - check Disabled cache - reload website. 
There will no cached data after reload. [check this image, disable cache must be checked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKBrM.png)